# How to iterate within a specific range of enum class with Hex value in Python

Tags: python, loops, class, for-loop, enums

I have the following class enum:

```
class LogLevel(Enum):
    level_1 = 0x30
    level_2 = 0x31
    level_3 = 0x32
    level_4 = 0x33
    level_5 = 0x34
    level_6 = 0x35
    level_7 = 0x36
    level_8 = 0x37
    level_9 = 0x38
```

I need to iterate from level_5 to level_6.

I tried islice() but haven't had any success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python enum iteration over subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957570/python-enum-iteration-over-subset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If levels sorted in ascending order then try:

```
list(LogLevel)[4:6]
```

which gives:

```
>> [<LogLevel.level_5: 52>, <LogLevel.level_6: 53>]
```

If levels are not sorted then try:

```
levels = ['level_5','level_6']
[i for i in list(LogLevel) if i.name in levels]
```

which gives

```
[<LogLevel.level_5: 52>, <LogLevel.level_6: 53>]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [LogLevel(i) for i in range(LogLevel.level_5.value, LogLevel.level_7.value)]
[<LogLevel.level_5: 52>, <LogLevel.level_6: 53>]
```

You can simplify that by using `IntEnum`:

```
>>> [LogLevel(i) for i in range(LogLevel.level_5, LogLevel.level_7)]
[<LogLevel.level_5: 52>, <LogLevel.level_6: 53>]
```